# Hooking up OpenCart with an iOS App via web services

Tags: ios, json, opencart

I need to develop an iOS app that fetches data from an OpenCart installation online. This includes ordering online, adding things to wish list, creating a user account. Logging in to an already existing user account and everything else that open cart offers. Basically, it is an iOS version of the OpenCart website that connects to the OpenCart's MySQL database.

I googled a little bit but couldn't find a proper API that I can use to hookup my app with OpenCart. What other options do I have? Does OpenCart offer any web service? (Like WordPress offers XML-RPC). Or is there a good API that I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, OpenCart **does not offer any API** straight away. (that's for an answer).

There is an opensource OpenCart API project on GitHub that you can download (google it, I do not remember it's name) but this offers only the very limited and basic methods for just reading of data (if I remember correctly there were methods for getting the list of categories, list of products and product details and few more).

This could be your starting point: fork, add methods, share. Or create your own API from a scratch if you wish (again, sharing will be highly welcomed :-) - I believe you could even find users willing to pay for it - I would have created one if I had time - but sadly I have not...).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
include_once 'functions.php';
class ControllerJsonJson extends Controller {
public function index() {            
// Menu
$this->load->model('catalog/category');

$this->load->model('catalog/product');

$this->load->model('tool/image');

$data['categories'] = array();

$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);

foreach ($categories as $category) {
if ($category['top']) {                                
// Level 2
$children_data = array();

$children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);                                                                

foreach ($children as $child) {
if ($child['image']) {
$childpopup = $this->model_tool_image->resize($child['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
$childthumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($child['image'], 74,74);
} else {
$childthumb='';
$childpopup = '';
}
$filter_data = array(
'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
'filter_sub_category' => true
);

$children_data[] = array(
'popup'=>$childpopup,
'thumb'=>$childthumb,
'id'  => $child['category_id'],
'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
);
}

if ($category['image']) {
$categorypopup = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
$categorythumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($category['image'], 74,74);
} else {
$categorypopup = '';
$categorythumb='';
}

// Level 1
$data['categories'][] = array(      
'popup'     => $categorypopup,
'thumb'     => $categorythumb,
'id'     => $category['category_id'],
'name'     => $category['name'],
'children' => $children_data,
'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
);
}
}

$obj=new functions();                
echo $obj->json_pretty_encode($data); 
}    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class functions {
    //put your code here


    public function json_pretty_encode($obj){
            header("Content-type: application/json");

            $json = json_encode($obj);

            if (!$json) return $json;

            $f = '';
            $len = strlen($json);

            $depth = 0;
            $newline = false;

            for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i)
            {
             if ($newline)
             {
              $f .= "\n";
              $f .= str_repeat(' ', $depth);
              $newline = false;
             }

             $c = $json[$i];
             if ($c == '{' || $c == '[')
             {
              $f .= $c;
              $depth++;
              $newline = true;
             }
             else if ($c == '}' || $c == ']')
             {
              $depth--;
              $f .= "\n";
              $f .= str_repeat(' ', $depth);
              $f .= $c;
             }
             else if ($c == '"')
             {
              $s = $i;
              do {
               $c = $json[++$i];
               if ($c == '\\')
               {
                $i += 2;
                $c = $json[$i];
               }
              } while ($c != '"');
              $f .= substr($json, $s, $i-$s+1);
             }
             else if ($c == ':')
             {
              $f .= ': ';
             }  
             else if ($c == ',')
             {
              $f .= ',';
              $newline = true;
             }
             else
             {
              $f .= $c;
             }
            }

            return $f;
           }


}
```